# className null or not an object again

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, error-handling

The problem with IE.
Here is the code:

```
if (($.browser.msie)) {
    var first_el = 0;
    var targie = document.getElementById(targId).getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < targie.length, first_el < 1; i++) {
        if ((typeof targie[i].className != 'undefined') && (targie[i].className != null)) {
            if ((targie[i].className == "category list even") || (targie[i].className == "category list") || (targie[i].className == "good list even") || (targie[i].className == "good list")) {
                var targ = targie[i];
                first_el += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error - `className null or not an object`
Found a similar topics, but the solutions did not help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the actual error message. It is more like `cannot access property "classname", targie[i] is null or not an object`, isn't it?

Your problem seems to be the condition part of your loop: `i < targie.length, first_el < 1` which uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This means your loop will run as long as it did not find an element - even if there are no more elements. Change it to `i < targie.length && first_el < 1` and it should work.

Btw, you seem to use jQuery. Why don't you use a DOM selector like `$("#"+targid+" div.list")`? Then, you could use an each loop to set up your variables, or just add a `:first` selector and go on with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything is ok.
I don't use a selector, because I need to continue with object method, which is not present in JQuery

Comment: I like a begginer in JS, maybe you know, how to make equivalent an object returned by selector and an object returned by document.getElementByWhatever?

Comment: You can easily return the DOM element from jQuery, and as this makes the code easier I'd highly recommend it. Could you append the surrounding code to your question?

Comment: Than why when I use alert($('.class')) and alert(document.getElementByClassName('class')), I see different things? And when I trying to use some JS methods on $() it sometimes shows an error?

Comment: the one is a `NodeList`, the other one a `jQuery` instance. Both contain a set of item (and even both could be accessed using a loop and bracket notation), but jQuery has a lot of useful methods on its prototype. However, they're still different - show us those functions, we can fix them

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `getAttribute('class');` if user's broser is IE